# Scaling a signal on a 2D Graphic pane

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm, graphics, 2d

I am scratching my head to figure out a way to scale a signal on a 2D graphic pane. The story is: I connect my application to a microcontroller and on fixed intervals I read a data value (A voltage point). Now I want to draw this on my graphic pane. Example:

[image]

So up in the picture you see at time 0, the voltage is also 0 and this goes on and after 6 data points I will clear the pane and redo the whole stuff.

The question is, how can I translate this voltage into pixel values, having in mind I want the middle of the graphic pane to be my signals 0, just like a normal cartesian graph. Can someone please help me to figure out the scaling algorithm in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like simple math: just add the width/2 to all X coordinates which you are passing into drawing functions. Suppose you have an array of 6 points you can do the following:

```
var g = this.CreateGraphics();
var points = new Point[6]{new Point(0, 0), new Point(10, 10), new Point(30, 0), new Point(40,20), new Point(50, 0), new Point(60,30)};
for (int i = 0; i < points.Length-1; i++)
{
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, points[i].X + Width / 2, Height / 2 - points[i].Y, points[i + 1].X + Width / 2, Height / 2 - points[i + 1].Y);
}
```

Alternatively you can invoke `TranslateTransform` function to move all further drawing to some amount by X and Y axes. Example:

```
var g = this.CreateGraphics();
var points = new Point[6]{new Point(0, 0), new Point(10, 10), new Point(30, 0), new Point(40,20), new Point(50, 0), new Point(60,30)};
g.TranslateTransform(Width / 2, 0, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append);
for (int i = 0; i < points.Length-1; i++)
{
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, points[i].X, Height / 2 - points[i].Y, points[i + 1].X, Height / 2 - points[i + 1].Y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be useful (remember that scale and translate functions are changing points in array):

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var points = new PointF[6] { new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(30, 3), new PointF(90, 0), new PointF(190, 3.1f), new PointF(270, -0.5f), new PointF(360, 3.5f) };

    float maxX = (from p in points select p).Max(t => t.X);
    float maxY = (from p in points select p).Max(t => t.Y);            

    float xSizeToFit = pictureBox1.Width;
    float ySizeToFit = pictureBox1.Height/2;
    float scaleX = xSizeToFit / maxX;
    float scaleY = ySizeToFit / maxY;

    // scale to fit to given size
    ScalePoints(points, scaleX, scaleY);
    // translate to center
    TranslatePoints(points, this.pictureBox1.Width / 2 - 0.5f * xSizeToFit, this.pictureBox1.Height / 2 + 0.5f * ySizeToFit);

    DrawAxis(e.Graphics, this.pictureBox1.Size);
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points);                
}

private void TranslatePoints(PointF[] points, float transX, float transY)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        points[i].X += transX;
        points[i].Y = transY - points[i].Y;
    }
}

private void ScalePoints(PointF[] points, float scaleX, float scaleY)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        points[i].X *= scaleX;
        points[i].Y *= scaleY;
    }
}

public void DrawAxis(Graphics g, Size size)
{
    //x
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, size.Height / 2, size.Width, size.Height / 2);
    //y
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, size.Width / 2, size.Height, size.Width / 2, 0);           
}

private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```